# AWS API throws error when unicode is included in payload

Tags: amazon-web-services, unicode, aws-lambda, serverless, aws-serverless

I am sending the following payload - it works fine in my local.

[image]

When I try the same payload on AWS API server. It throws the following error.

> 400 Bad Request: The browser (or proxy) sent a request that this
>   server could not understand.

AWS server is not able to process Unicode characters.

Please help me out, how to fix it.

p.s: we are using both serverless and API.

Comment: Try and use UTF-8 characters to send in the request. Link to utf-8 - https://apps.timwhitlock.info/emoji/tables/unicode